# Gradle: Run finalizedBy when task is interrupted (ctrl-c)

Tags: gradle

In Gradle, is it possible to run a finalizedBy if a subsequent operation has been interrupted with a ctrl-c? I think this would mean binding a task to a systems shutdown hook. An example project would look something like:

```
task prepare << {
    println "preparing"
}
task longOperation << {
    sleep 50000
}
longOperation.dependsOn prepare
task cleanup << {
    println "clean"
}
prepare.finalizedBy cleanup
cleanup.mustRunAfter longOperation
```

Ideally I'd want 'cleanup' to run regardless of the result of 'longOperation', but users can get impatient and ctrl-c the task and the entire gradle JVM shuts down (understandably) and then cleanup does not get run, a la:

```
$ ./gradlew -b /tmp/blah.gradle longOperation
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.
:prepare
preparing
> Building 33% > :longOperation^C
```

Disclaimer: This an old yet unanswered question from the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/run-finalizedby-when-task-is-interrupted-ctrl-c/3084).

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, No where in the Gradle's documentation or API do I see any sort of hook for `SIGINT` or similar.

This is probably by design choice since that is low level. You'll probably need to create something custom using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and override/implement the [`destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#destroy()) method of `Process`. Again this is low level work that it may be better to explore alternatives that Gradle offers.

One possible alternative would to be to always invoke the `clean` task before `longOperation`. So:

```
longOperation.dependsOn clean, prepare
```

But I think a better solution would be to utiltize the [Worker API](https://guides.gradle.org/using-the-worker-api/) in some way.